# How achieve this without using full outer join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this tables:

1) `customfields`

```
+------+---------+-------+
|userid| fieldid | value |
+------+---------+-------+
|  1   |   1     |  5c54 |
|  2   |   1     |  cerc |
|  2   |   3     |  3545 |
```

2) `users`

```
+------+---------+
|userid| name    |
+------+---------+
|  1   |   ale   |
|  2   |   ben   |
|  3   |   jak   |
```

I want to achieve:

`piva`: `fieldid` = 1 in the table `customfields`

`code`: `fieldid` = 3 in the table `customfields`

```
+--------+---------+-------+
|name    | piva    | code  |
+--------+---------+-------+
|  ale   |   5c54  |       |
|  ben   |   cerc  |  3545 |
```

I don't know how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT c.userid, u.name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN fieldid = 1 THEN value END) AS piva,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fieldid = 3 THEN value END) AS code
FROM customfields AS c
INNER JOIN users AS u ON c.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY c.userid, u.name
```

Comment: It is great, but I would love to be able to understand what is happening, can you help me?

Comment: @ciaoben Using a `CASE` exprerssion we can generate a value for each `fieldid` value, i.e a value when `fieldid = 1` and a value when `fieldid = 3`. `MAX` just returns this value.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a `full outer join` (which MySQL does not support).  One method is just a join with conditional aggregation:

```
select u.name,
       max(case when cf.fieldid = 1 then value end) as piva,
       max(case when cf.fieldid = 3 then value end) as code
from customfields cf join
     users u
     using (userid)
group by u.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this SQL-Query:

```
Select u.name,
(Select value from customfields where fieldid = 1 and userid= u.userid) as piva, 
(Select value from customfields where fieldid =3 and userid = u.userid) as code 
from users u
```